# How to solve H2 database `Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "INTEGER" are not comparable` syntax error?

Tags: hibernate, h2

I have an H2 column of type Boolean but Hibernate query it using a `1`/`0` instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, which leads to the `Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "INTEGER" are not comparable` syntax error.

For instance, Hibernate 5 will write

```sql
WHERE myBooleanColumn = 1
```

instead of

```sql
WHERE myBooleanColumn = TRUE
```

How can this be solved?

My H2 database version is  2.0.206 and I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.6.

Comment: I've never had to do such a thing. What dialect did you have in your config? Instead of hacking the dialect, try `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, the problem arises when one column is defined as boolean but Hibernate provides a 1/0 value instead of true/false. , for whatever reason, This issue had also been reported on [H2 support group](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/AKjKqvGr9j8/m/PSeVii0JBQAJ). Thanks.

Comment: Equating 1/0 with true/false would be correct behaviour if H2 mode was set to `MySQL`. Try adding `;MODE=PostgreSQL` (or whatever your DB is - [many are supported](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)) to your jdbc connection url, ie `jdbc:h2:...;MODE=PostgreSQL`. btw, what *is* your jdbc url?

Comment: The real DB is Oracle. The datasource is initialized programmatically because I need `mode.limit=true` hack to not get syntax error on the `LIMIT` clause : 
  @Bean
  @Profile("test")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    // Ref https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/yxnv64Ak-u8/m/n-kqYV_yBQAJ
    org.h2.engine.Mode mode = org.h2.engine.Mode.getInstance("ORACLE");
    mode.limit = true;

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:vessaging;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");

Comment: Staggeringly, and IMHO unacceptably, Oracle does't have a boolean datatype. Traditionally, `char` is used and `Y` and `N` values stored, but `numeric` storing `1` and `0` is also frequently used. Sounds like H2 picked that later. What datatype is your "boolean" column?

Comment: Indeed, it is `char` but the entity column type is Boolean. E.g. :
  `@Column(name = "IS_BROADCAST")` `private Boolean isBroadcast;`
So H2 creates a boolean column.

Answer (score 8):

You can you can create a class that will override the Hibenate's `Dialect` `toBooleanValueString` method :

```java
package com.myCorp;

import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;

public class H2DialectExtended extends H2Dialect {

    @Override
    public String toBooleanValueString(boolean bool) {
        return bool ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    }

}
```

And load it in your Spring Boot testing `application-test.properties` :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.myCorp.H2DialectExtended
```

This way, Hibernate will write :

```sql
WHERE myBooleanColumn = TRUE
```

instead of

```sql
WHERE myBooleanColumn =  1
```

Which will solve the problem as the myBooleanColumn is of type H2 Boolean.

Comment: This did work for me. Spring Boot 2.7.1. Strange that I would have to do this when they upped the version of H2 to 2.x in Spring Boot 2.7.0.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (in case you are using Oracle mode) :

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class H2WithOracleModeTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName(UUID.randomUUID() + ";Mode=Oracle;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH")
                .build();
        Mode mode = Mode.getInstance("ORACLE");
        mode.limit = true;
        // Here is the trick
        mode.numericWithBooleanComparison = true;
        return embeddedDatabase;
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.X and H2 2.1.214.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same issue and solved it differently, so I state my solution here if anyone in the future runs into this problem.

It is based on the comment of Bohemian (I tried to cite you, but I couldn't find a way, sorry.

He suggested changing the connection mode in the JDBC string. My connection string was: `spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;NON_KEYWORDS=USER;` (I have a table 'user', so I needed to disable H2's keyword checking for 'user').

I had to specifically add the database mode '`MODE=MySQL`' for it to work with my boolean field.

This resulted in the final connection string: `spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;NON_KEYWORDS=USER;MODE=MySQL`

Comment: Adding `MODE=MySQL` fixed it for me also!

Comment: This one worked also for me. Many thanks @Herry!

Answer (score 2):

If you have error in type matching, you can use MODE=.... specifying it in `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL`
But for some reason, when I specified MODE=PostgreSQL, it didn't solve my problem.
Then I explicitly specified dialect for hibernate:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

And the error in type matching disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my unit test which uses h2 and it worked

```
@BeforeAll
static void setUp() {
    org.h2.engine.Mode mode = org.h2.engine.Mode.getInstance("ORACLE");
    mode.limit = true;
    mode.numericWithBooleKanComparison = true; //This fixes the issue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before any other solution, check your Hibernate version. Hibernate supports new versions of H2 since the version 5.6.5.Final. No dialect overriding or numericWithBooleKanComparison H2 config required.

Answer (score -1):

Configure these properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

or if you use yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

---

Consider upgrading to the [latest version of spring-boot](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot) (currently 2.6.2).